# Is there a setting that effects #region #endregion collapsing for Python VSCode?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-interactive

Last night the #region and #endregion were working fine in VSCode for .py (python) interactive notebook files.  Today, the gutter (carrot left of #region) has disappeared ctrl+k,ctrl+0 no longer collapses between #region and #endregion.  There's no way to collapse manually either.  The version of VSCode does not appear to have updated (1.63.2) from 4 wks ago. I tried reinstalling VSCode with multiple computer restarts, but the settings are all automatic and reloaded on startup again. Any suggestions would be appreciated.  Very odd if it's a bug since there doesn't appear to have been an update.
Picture below w/ no carrot for collapsing left of #region

[image: Picture w no carrot for collapsing the gutter]

Comment: This also just happened to me. I did a clean reinstall, and narrowed it down to the Microsoft Python extension. If I uninstall that extension, region folding works. If I install it, region folding stops working.

Comment: I posted at https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/discussions/18297 asking about this seeming regression.

Comment: Thanks Jeff.  Pylance version 2022.1.1 from a few days ago does appear to have caused the issue.  Rolling back to 2022.1.0 and restarting the computer fixed the issue.  Hopefully they catch the bug on the next release.

Answer (score 0):

Hi You can enable  code folding in settings in vs code.

just go to settings, type  code folding

Then under Editor: Folding, tick the box